# How can I set value if variable has contains special character in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is my html

```
<div id="price_CMT*_BTC">0.00</div>
<div id="price_ETH_BTC">0.00</div>
```

This is my script

```
$("#price_CMT*_BTC").text("0.00000632"); // Error
$("#price_ETH_BTC").text("0.02701"); // OK
```

Comment: Escape meta character `*` i.e. `$("#price_CMT\\*_BTC")`

Comment: See also: https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/faq/how-do-i-select-an-element-by-an-id-that-has-characters-used-in-css-notation/